# How can I make VS Intellisense in visual c++ make a char value display as a number?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When coding c++ in Visual Studio, I sometimes use `char`s to represent a 1-byte numeric value.  When I do this, I use `typedef char tinyint`.

Is there a way to tell Intellisense that any time I'm looking at a constant `tinyint`, that I want to look at the number rather than the ascii value?

This is what it displays right now (for BLACK_LOST = 42).

[image: mousing over a constant tinyint in VS]

Comment: But Visual Studio by default shows the numeric value before ASCII.

Comment: @VTT somehow I did not notice that in the debugger.  What about for Intellisense?

Comment: Intellisense does not show ASCII value at all...

Comment: @VTT for constants, it does

Comment: [No, it does not.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ikout.png) Which VS version are you using?

Comment: It seems that C files and C++ files are treated differently. My screenshot is from a C file.